# Finding Test PDFs for text extraction?

Tags: pdf, testing

This is not exactly a programming question so I'm not sure if it is appropriate to post here?

Anyway, I've written a PDF text extractor and am looking for tricky PDFs to use to test it. I've searched extensively online and all the PDFs I've found work.

However, I know there are some that I have yet to test.

For example I can't seem to find a PDF with a CID font that is missing a "ToUnicode" entry.

Also, I can't seem to find any PDFs with tricky or confusing PostScript.

Can anyone recommend any?

Comment: *For example I can't seem to find a PDF with a CID font that is missing a "ToUnicode" entry.* - How about taking one with a ToUnicode map and removing it?

Comment: If you are interested in a real test of your text extractor, you should make it publicly available for others to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start testing with these (simple, but tricky) hand-written PDFs:

- **[Text Extraction Test-PDFs](https://github.com/angea/PDF101/tree/master/handcoded/textextract)** (handcoded)

To test with a real-world PDF file which had some of the `/ToUnicode` tables removed, see here:

- **[Troopers15 Presentation Slides](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hdTUPc8Sj1d2Z3SjRXY0tabG8/view?usp=sharing)** (Text not extractable)

Comment: Thats great thanks a lot! Do you have any more test PDFs? Maybe one thats missing the /ToUnicode but also has a CMap entry?